# Search DataGridView headers for specific name and if present, add specific item to ComboBox

Tags: vb.net-2010

Using MS Visual Basic 2010, I am importing a csv file into a DataGridView.  The first row of the csv file imports as the header in the DataGridView (HDR=Yes).   On the same form is a ComboBox.   Once the csv file imports into the DataGridView, I would like to search the header row for the value “Temp” and if it exists, add to the ComboBox the Item “Local Temperature”.   Then continue searching to see if a specific, second header exists and if so, add to the ComboBox a second specified Item.  And so on…   A header may not exist in the DataGridView and in that case, the program will move on to search if the next header name exists and if so, add a specific item name to the ComboBox.  Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find the code and wanted to share with the forum:

```
Dim dropDownItemsByColumnHeader As New Dictionary(Of String, String) From {{"Temp", "Local Temperature"},
                                                                           {"Column Header", "Drop-down Item"}}
Dim columnHeaders = Me.DataGridView1.Columns.Cast(Of DataGridViewColumn)().Select(Function(column) column.HeaderText)

For Each columnHeader In dropDownItemsByColumnHeader.Keys
    If columnHeaders.Contains(columnHeader) Then
        Me.ComboBox1.Items.Add(dropDownItemsByColumnHeader(columnHeader))
    End If
Next
```